# View in a Bottom edge removal transition gets stuck in a sheet when going from medium to large detent

Tags: swift, swiftui

It is hard to describe the issue in words. Here is a video that shows the issue very apparently.

https://streamable.com/1rnka7

When I press the "Go back to View 1" button as I swipe up the sheet to the large detent, the view 2 is still stuck at the bottom.

How do I fix this?

Here is my basic code to demonstrate the issue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingView2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.purple
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                Group {
                    if showingView2 {
                        VStack(spacing: 30) {
                            Text("View 2")

                            Button("Go to View 1") {
                                withAnimation(.default.speed(1.8)) {
                                    showingView2 = false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(.green)
                        .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom), removal: .move(edge: .bottom)))
                    } else {
                        VStack(spacing: 30) {
                            Text("View 1")

                            Button("Go to View 2") {
                                withAnimation(.default.speed(1.8)) {
                                    showingView2 = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .interactiveDismissDisabled()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use “constant” in any other place other than Preview.